# How to enter left parentheses into a text box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement to pass the text "English (United States)" into a text box.  But when I am using the below command:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("defaultLang")).sendKeys("English (United States)");
```

It is entering only **"English United States)** into the text box.  the Open Parentheses is missing when WebDriver is writing the text into the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

By using this you can enter the left parenthesis in text box.

```
    String a = (Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,"9"));
    String b = "AAA";
    String c = "BBB)";
    driver.findElement(By.id("ID")).sendKeys(b+a+c);
```

Resultant O/P is : AAA(BBB)

Answer (score 0):

You should use escape to send special characteres in selenium web driver,

I think you can try something like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("defaultLang")).sendKeys("English \(United States\)");
```

I hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known bug. See issue 6822 [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6822).

What you can do now, is to set it by injecting JavaScript directly.

```
// untested Java code, provides only the logic, you need debug yourself
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1]);", driver.findElement(By.id("defaultLang")), "English (United States)");
```